# How to schedule the creation of a widget in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a GUI application in kivy where one function that will get activated on a button press schedules the execution of another function at a later time, which creates a new widget.

This is what I am attempting to implement.

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
Builder.load_file('test.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):

    def schedule_widget(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(MyLayout.add_label, 5)

    def add_label(self):
        self.ids.id.add_widget(Label(text=f'Hello World'))

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height
        id: id
        Button:
            text: 'Add A Label in 5 seconds'
            on_release: app.root.schedule_widget()
```

It crashes and returns the error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ids'`, when the button is clicked. If I replace the `on_release:` to directly execute the `add_label` function, it successfully adds the label even though it is doing the same thing, just without the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating `add_label()` as a static method, but it is not. The error comes from `add_label()` expecting its argument to be `self`, but instead it is getting the `dt` (delta time) provided by `Clock.schedule_once()`. Try modifying your `MyLayout` class as:

```
class MyLayout(Widget):

    def schedule_widget(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_label, 5)  # use `self` to access method

    def add_label(self, dt):  # add dt argument
        self.ids.layoutId.add_widget(Label(text=f'Hello World'))  # use correct id
```

Comment: Thank you. I accidentally mixed up ID's when I typed the code into stack overflow. I updated my post so the .kv file and .py file use the same ID.